# Python list index out of range, a 6000 element list

Tags: python

I have a 6000+ elements list (called area_num) to work with. My code looks like:

```
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def getBusInfo_AreaName(area_num):
      area_name=[]
       for i in range(0,TotalBusNumber) :
           area_name[0][i]= AreaNameList[0][area_num[0][i]]

    return area_name
   #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   area_name=getBusInfo_AreaName(area_num)
```

And AreaNameList will be [[A,B,C,D,E,F]] include only 6 elements. I need the area name if I know the area number. Each object has area number and area name as its attributes.

Information:

TotalBusNumber=6000+

area_num[0] has 6000+ elements

Please give me some idea why Pyhton always complain 'list index out of range...'

Thank you all!

Comment: Don't just dump a small fragment of code (especially invalid code with an IndentationError) and a description of the error, give us actual code that reproduces the problem and the actual exception traceback. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help for guidance. This makes it much easier for people to debug your problem without having to guess.

Comment: how many elements are in `area_name[0]` and what value is in `TotalBusNumber`?

Comment: Also, I don't know if this is your problem or not, but `[[A,B,C,D,E,F]]` doesn't include 6 elements, it includes 1 element (that happens to itself be a list that includes 6 elements).

Comment: @tttthomasssss This error is likely coming from indexing in to `area_num[0]`, not `area_name[0]` (unless either of those are 0 length of course), but otherwise, exactly the question to be asking.

Comment: there is a lot of indexing in `area_name[0][i]= AreaNameList[0][area_num[0][i]]`. Just for debug, try referencing each of these individually above this line. Python tells you the line with the error and you know which index you got wrong.

Comment: @tttthomasssss Pleae see the updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't create list items just because you reference them. `area_name[0][i]` doesn't exist, so an exception is thrown. I'm not sure what this code is doing, but it seams that all you want to do is copy a sublist.

```
def getBusInfo_AreaName(area_num):
    area_name=[]
    area_name.append(area_num[0][:])
    return area_name
```

This could be thinned a bit more, but I presume its all just example code anyway.